# How to disambiguate generic trait method call?

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```rust
struct X { i: i32 }

trait MyTrait<T> {
    fn hello(&self);
}

impl MyTrait<i32> for X {
    fn hello(&self) { println!("I'm an i32") }
}

impl MyTrait<String> for X {
    fn hello(&self) { println!("I'm a String") }
}

fn main() {
    let f = X { i: 0 };
    f.hello();
}
```

which obviously does not compile as the compiler cannot disambiguate to which trait the `f.hello()` belongs. So I'm getting the error

```rust
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src\main.rs:17:7
   |
17 |     f.hello();
   |       ^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the trait `MyTrait`
```

Is there any way to annotate the type of `hello` so I can tell the compiler to e.g. invoke `MyTrait<String>::hello` on `f`?

Comment: Commenting to link to [How do I disambiguate traits in Rust?](/questions/44953197/how-do-i-disambiguate-traits-in-rust) and also [How to call a method when a trait and struct use the same method name?](/questions/44445730/how-to-call-a-method-when-a-trait-and-struct-use-the-same-method-name)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some digging in I bumped into the ["Fully Qualified Syntax for Disambiguation: Calling Methods with the Same Name" from the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name). The situation can be adapted to mine, and one can use `f` as a receiver for the corresponding trait method

```
<X as MyTrait<String>>::hello(&f);
```

This compiles and works as intended.

Or even

```
<MyTrait<String>>::hello(&f);
```

works.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [fully qualified function call syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/call-expr.html#disambiguating-function-calls):

```
fn main() {
    let f: X;

    // shorthand form
    MyTrait::<String>::hello(&f);

    // expanded form, with deduced type
    <_ as MyTrait<String>>::hello(&f);

    // expanded form, with explicit type
    <X as MyTrait<String>>::hello(&f);
}
```

[Run in Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=606580aed4cf070f434a7ede1c1e5171)